# Jupyter Slideshow in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, slideshow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-extensions

I am trying to edit and present a slideshow inside of VSCode using Jupyter Notebooks (on a Windows 11 computer).  I can make Jupyter notebooks, and I have the Jupyter Slide Show extension installed in VSCode.  Picture shown below:

[image: screen grab of VSCode]

As you can see, I've marked the markdown cell as a slide. However, none of the menu options at the top bar, nor for the code's tab, nor for the `...` on the right hand side, nor the gear menu, says anything about rendering as a slideshow presentation.  Does anyone know how to actually make the slideshow?